# ASP.NET MVC - create custom route without a fallback

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm creating an MVC project and I have the following link that leads to a list of websites for the logged in user:

```
http://[server]/Members/Websites
```

now I would like to add a new custom route under the websites part of the user that will lead to a service connection page:

```
http://[server]/Members/Websites/Connect-to-service/999
```

where "999" is the id of the website that is being connected.

I've defined the following route for that manned (placing it above the default route):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "myRoute",
    url: "Members/Websites/Connect-to-service/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Members", action = "Connect_To_Service" }
);
```

now, if I enter the url "http://[server]/Members/Websites/Connect-to-service/999" it loads my page fine.

if I enter the url "http://[server]/Members/Websites/Connect-to-service/" it loads the websites page.

what I would like to have is when loading "http://[server]/Members/Websites/Connect-to-service/" it will either redirect to "http://[server]/Members/Websites/" (in the browser url), or throw a page not found error.

can this be done?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could configure this in the `Connect_To_Service` action:

```
public ActionResult Connect_To_Service(int? id = null)
{
    if (!id.HasValue)
    {
        // Either:
        return RedirectToAction("Websites", "Members");

        // Or:
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    // An id is provided. Process..
}
```

You might need to change your route by adding a default value for `id`:

```
defaults: new { controller = "Members", action = "Connect_To_Service", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```